# Flutter Dart Process.run Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: dart, process, flutter-windows

I'm trying to run a command line using dart's `Process.run`

Here is my code

```
var result = await Process.run('axmldec', [ '-o','C:/test/output.xml'
      , 'C:/test/AndroidManifest.xml' ]);
```

thought the problem is the slash / so I also tried this

```
var result = await Process.run('axmldec', [ '-o','C:\\test\\output.xml'
      , 'C:\\test\\AndroidManifest.xml' ]);
```

Tried C: and D: drives with no luck. The error I get is

```
Command: axmldec -o D:/test/output.xml D:/test/AndroidManifest.xml
#0      _ProcessImpl._start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:390:33)
#1      Process.start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:36:20)
#2      _runNonInteractiveProcess (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:565:18)
#3      Process.run (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:47:12)
#4      Home._testUnzip (package:apk_analysis/main.dart:112:32)
#5      Home.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:apk_analysis/main.dart:60:25)
#6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
#7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
#8      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18)
#9      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)
#11     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:539:5)
#12     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:254:13)
#13     FilePickerCross.importMultipleFromStorage (package:file_picker_cross/file_picker_cross.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

And when I run the same command in the command line it works without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem seemed to be path of the command itself "axmldec"

despite having that set in the environment variables, dart process did not recognize it.  I used the full path and it worked

```
var result = Process.run('c:\\tool\\axmldec.exe', [ '-o','D:\\test\\output.xml'
      , 'D:\\test\\AndroidManifest.xml' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking `runInShell` to true may help when running commands (such as the `flutter` commnad).

```dart
Process.run(
  'flutter',
  [ 'create', 'example' ],
  runInShell: true,
  workingDirectory: directory,
);
```